# How can I Resume Thread once join() is called?

Tags: c++, multithreading

This is my sender thread once after it is called for first time its finish its execution. I Couldn't be able to resume this sender thread. Is There any mechanism in C++ to resume threads.

```
void ClientSocket::sender()
{


    char buf[1024]; 
        //readBuffer = m_ptrsendStream->Read_Adt(filePath);
        //readStream();
        //cout << readBuffer.str()<<endl;
        cout << "write stream to send through socket\n" << endl;
        cin >> buf;
        if (isConnected == 0)
        {

            //send(clientSock, readBuffer.str().c_str(), strlen((char *)readBuffer.str().c_str()), 0);
            send(clientSock, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
            cout << "sending stream :\n"<<endl << buf << endl;

        }

}

//this is where my thread creation happens and join() happens.

int  main(int argc, char *argv[])
{



    ClientSocket objSocket(argv[1]);

        sender_thread = make_shared<thread>([&objSocket]() {
            objSocket.sender();
        });



        try
        {


    if (sender_thread->joinable())
            sender_thread->join();

        }
```

Answer (score 4):

No, once your thread has joined it's done and you need to create a new one.

If you have this pattern where you are constantly creating new threads it might be worthwhile to think about using a threadpool to avoid the overhead of constantly spawning new threads.

In addition, if this is related to networking it's probably best to avoid using threads and instead use something asynchronous like [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

Answer (score 3):

1. Terminated threads cannot be resumed (this is not a C++ limitation, but a general limitation; when speaking about resuming thread, it is usually about resuming after previously suspending it).
2. After join() has returned, corresponding thread is already terminated; it has no state (except maybe for zobmie stuff and return code, but this is of no use for your purposes), and there is nothing to resume
3. However, it is possible to run your sender() function in another thread, just create another instance of your thread.

EDIT: I concur with @inf on using asio instead of threads whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

You want resume thread which is completed , normally thread resume used continue from suspended threads . Instead of resuming the thread ,stop come of thread un till it finish all actions , make use of while or wait in thread .